# Multiply Matrixes in C# for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, matrix, windows-phone, matrix-multiplication

I am using the [`Matrix`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.media.matrix%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class that is available in .NET for Windows Phone.

Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to multiply two objects of this class. Should I do it myself or does a helper method exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `MatrixTransform` seems to be a solution :)